# How do I roast eggplants without a gas stove?

Tags: roasting, eggplant

There is an Indian dish that requires roasting eggplants on high heat directly on a gas stove until charred, like this:

[image: eggplant on gas burner] [image: charred eggplant]

Here's a [recipe](http://www.finecooking.com/recipes/eggplant_fragrant_spices.aspx) for the dish. Everything else is fine but I do not have a flame top stove, instead I have one with an electrical top. I would really appreciate any ideas to help me with roasting the eggplant. I have an oven but not a grill/barbecue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use the the broiler (or grill, as they say in the UK).
2. Use a wok ring or similar to suspend the eggplant above your electric element.  Set the element to its highest setting, cooking the eggplant by infrared.  It just may take longer than the gas element would have.   If you don't have a wok  ring, you can use aluminum foil crushed to improvise an eggplant stand.
3. Buy a small hibachi and use it—the original recipe is designed for a grill (in the US sense, barbecue in the UK parlance).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used a pan instead of a grill and it worked the same. However, I used low setting instead of high.

Comment: You can use the same technique for roasting other veggies too. Bell peppers, tomatoes, chilies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

you can also roast it on cast iron shallow pan, will give the best results. But firstly at low settings then to medium settings.